# Composer "Dag Bag size" much larger than number of DAGs

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a Cloud Composer environment, version `composer-1.17.1-airflow-2.1.2`. In this environment I currently have 27 DAGs.

However, when I go to the Monitoring page for the environment, and click on "Show DAG Metrics," the chart for "DAG bag size" shows a size of 137.

Is it cause for concern to see that it isn't equal to the number of DAGs? Could it actually reflect the total number of DAG Runs, or perhaps the number of operators? What influences the size of this metric, and how do I know if the metric is healthy?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [Cloud Composer metrics document](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/monitoring-dashboard#dag_runs), it shows the number of DAGs deployed in a bucket and processed by Airflow at a given time.

> DAG bag size
>
> A chart showing the number of DAGs deployed to a Cloud Storage bucket and processed by Airflow at a given time. This can be helpful when analyzing performance bottlenecks. For example, an increased number of DAG deployments may degrade performance due to excessive load.

So in your case that should be 27, and it is not possible for other Composer instances to share a bucket. Thus the increase in number should be because of the **DAGs processed/run at a given time**.